# How to define spinors in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, spinors

In Schwartz's QFT and the Standard Model, a vector is defined an object that transforms like a vector. For instance, $V$ is a 4-vector if its components transform like this under Lorentz boost,

\begin{equation}
V_\mu \rightarrow \Lambda_{\mu\nu}V_\nu
\end{equation}

Where $\Lambda_{\mu\nu}$ are elements of Lorentz matrix. The book then talks about the commutator of Lorentz group, and how other representations of Lorentz group can be found by constructing objects whose transformation rule obey the same commutation relation. In particular, a spin 1/2 fermion can be represented by a Dirac spinor. In later part of that book, they check if an operator is vector by testing its transformation rules under Lorentz transformation. It is a vector only if it follows the aforementioned transformation rule.

After finishing that book, I moved on to read Schutz's textbook on general relativity and am surprised to learn that they defined vector in an alternative way. They define it as

> "a vector is a tangent to some curve, and is the function that gives $d\phi/ds$ when it takes $\tilde{d}\phi$ as an argument".

Or if I understand correctly, vector $\vec{V}$ is an object that when supplied as an input to a one-form with components $(d\phi/dx^i)$, produces an invariant number $d\phi/ds$ where $s$ is a parametrization of a curve with tangent $\vec{V}$ and $\phi$ is any scalar field.

This definition actually makes more sense to me as it doesn't rely on the apparently tautological definition of "transform like a vector" (I know it's not tautology as the rules of transformation are defined in advance, but still). Furthermore, this definition immediately extends to vectors in Riemannian spaces. I have no doubt that this definition leads to transformation rules that obeys the Lorentz commutator in a flat Minkowski space as both definitions lead to the same 4-vector.

But now I wonder, it is possible to define spinors in similar manner as well? Can spinors be defined in terms of one-forms and derivatives of $\phi$? The first idea that comes to my mind is to define $\phi$ as a Dirac spinor field rather than a scalar field, but that may ends up with 4 independent scalar rather than a Dirac spinor field. I guess I have to somehow uses gauge invariance properties? It seems to get technical and tedious soon.

At the moment, I am not interested (yet) in quantizing fields in curved spaces. I just want to know if there is an alternative definition of spinors in the context of differential geometry.

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation_in_curved_spacetime) help?

Comment: 1) Careful that you are more precise and do not confuse vectors (as elements of a tangent space) with vector fields, likewise spinors with spinor fields.

Comment: 2) If $V \in TM$ is a vector field on $M$, then in some coordinate patch we can write its restriction as $V = V^\mu \partial_\mu$, whilst on another coordinate patch $V = V^{\prime \mu}\partial'_\mu$. These must agree on the overlap so you rederive your 'transformation like a vector' rule. Conversely, if you have some set of $V^\mu$, $V^{\prime \mu}$s for each coordinate that transform like a vector, then you can sew them together to get a vector field. The two concepts are trivially identical, one is a mathematician's 'geometric' approach, the other a physicist's 'coordinate-first' approach

Comment: Thinking of sewing things together on manifolds is a very important concept so don't downplay it.

Comment: 3) Of course, you can try the same idea for a spinor field, but how are you going to define a spinor field in the first place? The usual definition (as a section of a spinor bundle) secretly requires the transformation property (representation) of a spinor. That's what the subscript $\kappa$ is doing in the equation in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor_bundle) wiki article. You are just using fancy mathematical terms for not any gain. (Of course I am not trying to downplay the importance of spinor bundles).

Comment: When it came time to incorporate spinors into GR, it was discovered that the fact that $+\sigma_z$ and $-\sigma_z$ refers to the same spinor direction means that we have to find an alternative way to define spinors as opposed to vectors. To do that, vierbeins are introduced, and the resulting theory is called Einstein-Cartan.

Comment: The Einstein-Dirac Equation on Riemannian Spin
Manifolds.   https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9905095.pdf